# FIlter the Symfony2 Admin Generator

Tags: symfony, filtering, propel, admin-generator

Hello to everyone I need manipulate the  data of the admin generator I have been reading the documentation but this dont help me. I need that a user only can see the information of his group and no more.

here is my generator.yml

```
generator: admingenerator.generator.propel
params:
model: Velfasa\SoporteBundle\Model\Usuario
namespace_prefix: Velfasa
concurrency_lock: ~
bundle_name: SoporteBundle
pk_requirement: ~
fields: ~
object_actions:
    delete: ~
batch_actions:
    delete: ~
builders:
list:
    params:
        title: Lista de usuarios
        display: [ nombre, apellido, dpi, username, direccion, fecha_de_nacimiento]
        actions:
            new:
                route: usuario_registro
        object_actions:
            edit:
                route: usuario_editar
            delete: ~
            show: 
                route: usuario_visualizar
filters:
    params:
        display: [nombre, email, apellido, dpi, username, direccion, fecha_de_nacimiento]
new:
    params:
        title: Nuevo usuario
        display: ~
        actions:
            save: ~
            list: ~
edit:
    params:
        title: Editar
        display: ~
        actions:
            save: ~
            list: ~
show:
    params:
        title: Vista general
        display: ~
        actions:
            list: ~
            new: ~
actions:
    params:
        object_actions:
            delete: ~
        batch_actions:
            delete: ~
```

Y expect that someone here can help me

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at [Security part of documentation](https://github.com/symfony2admingenerator/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/security/credentials.md) I think you should use credentials.

**Show / Edit / Delete Actions**

Edit your yml file and add credentials function for all object actions you want to secure (check ifOwnedByGroupSameAsCurrentUser ?). Maybe you come with better name ;)

```
# ...
params:
    # ...
    object_actions:
        show:
            credentials: 'ifOwnedByGroupSameAsCurrentUser(object)'
        edit:
            credentials: 'ifOwnedByGroupSameAsCurrentUser(object)'
        delete:
            credentials: 'ifOwnedByGroupSameAsCurrentUser(object)' 
    # ...
```

Now define function. Inside the same Bundle (dont work with external bundle) define Security class:

```
// src/MyPrefix/MyBundle/Security/AccessEvaluator.php
<?php

namespace MyPrefix\MyBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

/**
 * @DI\Service
 */
class AccessEvaluator
{

    private $container;

    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *     "container" = @DI\Inject("service_container"),
     * })
     */
    public function __construct( ContainerInterface $container )
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @DI\SecurityFunction("ifOwnedByGroupSameAsCurrentUser")
     */
    public function ifOwnedByGroupSameAsCurrentUser( $object )
    {
        // Get current user
        $user = $this->getCurrentUser();

        //
        // THIS IS THE MAGIC
        // change this part to check if user and object has the same group related
        // I assumed that the object has one related group and user can have more groups
        // 
        if( in_array( $object->getGroup(), $user->getGroups() ) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        // this function must return a boolean value
        return false;
    }

    protected function getCurrentUser()
    {
        // I use fos user bundle
        // replace with your own "get user" code
        $userManager = $this->container->get( 'fos_user.user_manager' );
        $user = $userManager->findUserByUsername( $this->container->get( 'security.context' )->getToken()->getUser() );

        return $user;
    }
}
```

**List Action**

To security List Action you need to edit ListController and override processQuery function. This function is made for this purpose, so no need to worry. And the proper way to limit access is to use AdminGenerator Filter methods:

```
// src/MyPrefix/MyBundle/Controller/MyController/ListController.php
// ...
protected function processFilters( $query )
{
    // Get current user
    $userManager = $this->get( 'fos_user.user_manager' );
    $user = $userManager->findUserByUsername( $this->get( 'security.context' )->getToken()->getUser() );

    $filterObject = $this->getFilters();
    $queryFilter = $this->getQueryFilter();
    $queryFilter->setQuery( $query );
    //
    // THIS IS THE MAGIC
    // change this part to check if user and object has the same group related
    // I assumed that the object has one related group and user can have more groups
    //        
    foreach( $user->getGroups() as $group )
    {
        $queryFilter->addEntityFilter( 'group', $group );
    }
    parent::processFilters( $query );
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I used is overwrite the List Controller on the method Query. Here you can set your personal query with any modification.

Comment: I think you mean method _processQuery_ with is generated for user modification purpose. For Edit/New Controllers you can also use _PreSave_ and _PostSave_ methods, with is very convenient. Still take a look at security part of documentation. This is "the way" of manage privileges.